# Eclipse with 2 monitors loss perspectives

Tags: eclipse, perspective, multiple-monitors

I use Windows 8 x64 and last eclipse: eclipse-java-juno-SR1.

At second monitor I move console and some android tools (logcat, devices). All worked ok. But I do not need see second monitor all time. And I switch off this monitor (by win + P). On next start I see windows from second monitor at primary monitor. Close. Open. And now see default perspective. Own perspectives, that I saved disappeared. And this repeat all time, if I disable second monitor.

Before I use eclipse-java-indigo-SR1 and do not have any problem.

Comment: Try finding this bug in [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) or file a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't find solution. Now back to indigo (3.7.1).